# Does docker use service name or container name to resolve service reference in docker compose?

Tags: docker-compose

```
redis:
    image: redis
    container_name: my-redis
```

If I had the above `docker compose.yml` file, then somewhere else where I need to, for example, reference the redis host, should I use `redis` or `my-redis` in the client connection string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use both to address redis, given the assumption you are in the same docker network.

```yaml
services:
  redis:
    image: redis
    container_name: my-redis
```

The container name will be *my-redis*, but it is also registered with the [network alias](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_connect/#create-a-network-alias-for-a-container) *redis*.

When you have only a single container, the alias may not be useful, or it may not be apparent why it's useful. It starts to become useful when you deploy something with more than 1 [replica](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#replicas).

You can see this by inspecting the container.

```sh
docker inspect my-redis
```

You can also leave the container name away to let compose use the default container name `<project>-<service>-<replica>` i.e. `myproject-redis-1`. In fact, this is required when you want to deploy multiple replicas because you cannot deploy multiple containers with the same name.

```yaml
name: myproject
services:
  redis:
    image: redis
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
```

Typically, people use the service name over the container name.